# How to send a csv file from machine 1 to machine 3 using nifi in machine 2?

Tags: database, hdfs, hbase, apache-nifi

I have 3 machines for my scenario
Machine 1:  has a .csv file
Machine 2: Nifi is installed and running
Machine 3: HDFS and Hbase is installed and running.

Now I have to send the .csv file from machine 1 to Hbase table running in machine 3 using nifi which is running in machine 2.

To get the file from machine 1 I am using GetSFTP processor and I could get the .csv file till nifi running in machine 2. Now I don't know which processor to use so that I can send the file to my hbase table running in machine 3? I have used PutHbaserecord  but that just help me in storing in habse table if my habse and hdfs is running in machine 2.

So can someone let me know how can is send to machine 3 using nifi?

> hbase-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>
 <property>
<name>hbase.rootdir</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
<value>2222</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
<value>/home/hadoop/zookeeper</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
<property>
<name>hbase.wal.provider</name>
<value>filesystem</value>
</property>
 <property>
<name>hbase.tmp.dir</name>
<value>./tmp</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

> core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
<value>/home/hdoop/tmpdata</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

> hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>


<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.name.dir</name>
<value>file:///home/hadoop/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.data.dir</name>
 <value>file:///home/hadoop/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you confirm you've properly configured HBase Client Service (Controller Service) of your PutHBaseRecord processor? You need to feed it the core-site.xml and hbase-site.xml so your NiFi can get to know your Hadoop/Hbase cluster.

Comment: I would like to put directly on hbase table not on hdfs directory files. Is that I need to change localhost:9000 to (publicaddressofmachine3):9000

Comment: Please put those configs in the question with proper formatting

Comment: To put files on HDFS use `PutHDFS` processor. Copy those config XMLs on NiFi node and configure `PutHDFS` to use those so that NiFi will be able to access HDFS.

Comment: I want to put the file on the HBase table, not to hdfs directory. Hbase is running on machine 3 and nifi on machine 2. All are under the same network.

Comment: As said before, you need to update your hbase and core configuration files to point NiFi to your machine 3. This is usually done by copying the files directly from the target cluster hadoop to the NiFi machine. If your machine 3 is like sandbox cluster or something like that, no FQDNs on hostnames, etc.. you might need to edit it manually on the NiFi machine so it can reach your machine 3 via the network. You might also need to change listener addresses on your machine 3 if they are listening only on localhost address (i.e: not reachable by the network)

Comment: I didn't use sandbox installation. I installed Hadoop and HBase through terminal commands and did configurations. I am very new to this domain so could you please explain with an example by using my above config file.

Comment: I couldnt connect. Machine 3 has a public IP through which I connect from pc using ssh name@xxx -p xx and in that I have a haddop with above specification. Now tell me what should i change in configuration so that i can connect to machine 3 from machine 1 using nifi

Answer (score 1):

> I have used PutHbaserecord but that just help me in storing in hbase table if my hbase and hdfs is running in machine 2

I don't think that's true. According to the documentation, you need to provide an HBase Client Service

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-hbase-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.hbase.PutHBaseRecord/

In this Service, you provide Hadoop configuration files (an hbase-site.xml) which would contain the IP:port information of the remote HBase cluster (via Zookeeper), which will not be localhost ; if Nifi is given (or Zookeeper returns) `localhost`, then yes, it'll think HBase is running on the Nifi node.

You should only need these set in the xml to connect to a distributed hbase cluster

- hbase.zookeeper.quorum
- hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort

By the way, hbase has its own CLI commands for importing CSV files, and Nifi seems like overkill for the simple task of uploading data

Comment: I couldnt connect. Machine 3 has a public IP through which I connect from pc using ssh name@xxx -p xx and in that I have a haddop with above specification. Now tell me what should i change in configuration so that i can connect to machine 3 from machine 1  using nifi.

Comment: You'll obviously need network connectivity to the hbase client port and the Zookeeper server it is connected to from all of the Nifi servers... Public ip nor ssh connections should matter

Comment: i have a pc (Machine 3) at office with above hadoop and hbase configuration. I have nifi installed in my personal system (Machine 2). How can I connect to machine 3 from machine 2 using nifi to send file ?

Comment: Like I said, if Zookeeper is storing and returning machine 3's IP/port during   config lookups for `hbase.zookeeper.quorum` and `hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort` , then it should work. As written in the docs, however, the default quorum property is localhost and remote clients will not be able to connect https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#zookeeper

Comment: I am very new to this domain hadoop and hdfs. So what should I do to connect the machine 2 and machine 3 ? which property or configurations I need to change for this. IN nifi I am passing the /usr/local/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml to hbase client service

Comment: Read the linked page on "pseudo distributed" Hbase setup. It tells you how to link hbase to the namenode. Only in distributed mode will external clients work

Comment: Do i also need hadoop to be in fully distributed mode or is it okay to have single node cluster??

Comment: It's called pseudo-distributed, because it's only one node not "distributed". From a networking perspective, there's no difference